# In Ruby 1.9, should the regex /c?ab/ match "cab" or "ab" first?

Tags: ruby, regex

Example:

```
a = "abcab"

/c??ab/.match(a) # Matches "ab", as I expected
/c?ab/.match(a)  # Still matches "ab"
```

As I understand it, because the character `?` alone is greedy, it should first try and match the biggest string possible - cab -, but this is not the behavior I get in Ruby 1.9.

What is the expected behavior, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex as a whole is eager — it will try to match in the very first place it can. So `c?ab` and `c??ab` are equivalent: the only difference is in how long a substring they prefer to match, and they don't actually get the chance to exercise that preference.

---

To expand a bit on this . . . consider this:

```
/<.*>/.match("abcde<fghi>jkl<mn>o")
```

It will start matching at the first `<`, and because it's greedy, it will try to match as much as possible while still matching, which means it will match `<fghi>jkl<mn>`. If you change to a non-greedy quantifier:

```
/<.*?>/.match("abcde<fghi>jkl<mn>o")
```

it will still start matching at the first `<`, but will now try to match as little as possible while still matching, which means it will match just `<fghi>`. But it won't try to skip ahead to `<mn>` and match that, even though that's a shorter substring. The only way it would match `<mn>` is if it completely failed to match anywhere earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply - "the regex is eager" was the key phrase that helped me finding a detailed reply about how it works.

For future reference, the following link explains how it works in more depth:
[Laziness Instead of Greediness - www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

Comment: I think *"The regex as a whole is eager"* is misleading, as it implies something comparable to *greediness* and *non-greediness*, whereas all that is happening is that the regex engine is scanning the target string to find a point where the pattern can match. Greedy and non-greedy sub-patterns only have an effect if there is more than one way that the pattern can match at a given point. They cannot affect whether or not the overall pattern matches in the first place.

Comment: @Borodin: A *non-eager* regex engine would scan the target string from the end, trying to find the last position at which the regex can match. (I'm not aware of any such, but you can achieve the effect of one by prepending `.*` and using a capture group.) The rest of your comment, of course, is saying the same thing as my answer. :-)

Comment: @ruakh: I think you made up *eager* and *non-eager*! So `String#rindex` is eager? And I don't see where you made the points that I did.

Comment: @Borodin: Re: "I think you made up *eager* and *non-eager*!": They're not standard technical terms, if that's what you mean. They were simply my attempt to explain how it works. And my attempt was completely successful, so I don't know why you object! Re: "I don't see where you made the points that I did": The second sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Borodin As a non-native English speaker, ruakh 's explanation, while not too in-depth, make perfect distinction between the terms "eager" and "greedy" to me. As I understood it, being "eager" means that it is "anxious" to match as soon as possible, while being greedy means matching as much as possible - but in this case being eager takes precedence over being greedy. I wouldn't say (s)he made up the term "eager" though, as it is also mentioned in the link I have provided. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Vitamini & ruakh: I had not looked at the *regular-expressions.info* link, and I guess that was ruakh's inspiration for the term. But the page exemplifies my concern, because in the relevant paragraph there is a confusion between *backtracking* (altering submatches trying to make a complete match *at the current point in the string*) and simply *reporting the first match*. I don't think we need a label for the latter because it is just *"searching"*; it would be a special kind of search that, having found a match, ignored it and continued the search, and for *that* we would need a label.

Comment: @Borodin: Actually, I don't think I'd ever visited that page before. My inspiration for the term is that it's what the word *eager* means in English.